# Estimating distribution function in a repeated measurement design

Tags: distributions, repeated-measures

Suppose we have a repeated measurement design with imbalanced clusters so that $X_{1,1}, X_{1, 2}, \ldots X_{1, n_1} \sim F_1$,  $X_{2,1}, X_{2,2}, \ldots, X_{2,n_2} \sim F_2$, and $ X_{m, 1}\ldots, X_{m, n_m} \sim F_{m}$. We wish to estimate $F$ as the unconditional CDF, such as would be the average, population level distribution function, what we might express as $F(y) = \int_{X \in \Omega_X} F_X(y) dX$. In regression, we often use a mixed model with, say, a random intercept, but this modeling approach invokes some assumption about the distribution, such as a random normal error term. What methods might we use to estimate a more general $F$ with a random effects-type approach?